# How to check if SimpleXMLElement Object's attribute exist - PHP

Tags: php, xml, properties, simplexml

In the below code I'm trying to access `@attributes` of  `Userinfo`  as `$somevariable->Userinfo->attributes();` which is perfectly fine, but when there is no `@attributes` it throws an error

> Call to a member function attributes() on null

```
[Userinfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [UserId] => 121
            [UserName] => Arun, Singh
            [UserEmail] => abc@xyz.com
            [CreatedDate] => 06/27/2018 08:44:21
        )

)
```

So, before accessing `@attributes`, how to check if it exist ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the XML(and not the array version) and the actual code your using.  The error seems to indicate the `Userinfo` is not there rather than the attributes missing.

Comment: Yes @Nigel Ren this was the issue, actually `Userinfo` I'm getting from api dynamically, for some case it was not received I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `!empty()`

```
if(!empty($somevariable->Userinfo->attributes())){
  // do stuff here
}
```

Sample output:- https://3v4l.org/R32Bv

Or you can use `isset()` too

```
if(isset($somevariable->Userinfo)){
  // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: In your code I made some changes and found that it is enough to to check if `$somevariable->Userinfo` exist, however your code also works :).. thanks

Comment: @KArunSingh  glad to help you :):)